# Get posts from my Tumblr API

Tags: typescript, angular, tumblr

I need to get my tumblr posts over an api.

I've managed to setup the api key.
I'm using Angular2, typescript for this.

I'm using jsonp so that I dont get a cross origin issue.

**This is my current attempt:**

```
  var config = {
    params: {
      action: "query",
      prop: "revisions",
      format: "json",
      callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
    }
  }

  var url = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/thepoolcover.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=lqoK2G4BT9X8xnewyW0l45ky4aTKWTqQ3PzF14gefIglpIRnBz";

  this.jsonp.request(url, config).subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response);

  });
```

**I dont get a typescript compiler error, however, I do get a browser exception console error:**

[image]

Comment: The url works fine if you put it directly into the browser. It returns the posts in json. But I'm struggling to get it via the above code. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried a standard http get in angular 2 and I get a cross origin issue. Also, in the past I would do an ajax call but I'm not sure how to do that in angular2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use `JSONP_CALLBACK` for the name of the callback instead of `JSON_CALLBACK` and URLSeachParams for the query parameters:

```
URLSearchParams search = new URLSearchParams();
search.set('action', 'query');
search.set('prop', 'revisions');
search.set('format', 'json');
search.set('callback', 'JSONP_CALLBACK');

var config = {
  search: search
};

var url = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/thepoolcover.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=lqoK2G4BT9X8xnewyW0l45ky4aTKWTqQ3PzF14gefIglpIRnBz";

jsonp.request(url, config).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr:

- http://plnkr.co/edit/baXHgR3Hbu9tGMGsQXyY?p=preview

Comment: You should also use `URLSearchParams` for query parameters. I updated my answer...